# How to measure webpage performance?

Tags: performance, web

I am working on a single page web application. Now our target is improve the performance of the web application. I am responsible to improve improve the UI Performance. Our web application is single page web application where we get dynamic data from server via ajax calls and process that data with the help of various java script libraries and frame works and update the DOM.

With that context, first I would like to measure the current performance and find out bottle neck areas where I can improve the performance. I am more interested to measure performance after web resources like scripts, styles. I would like to measure how much time it takes to render and display the content to the user after we got all the resources from the server. And I would like to find out bottlenecks after loading the page.

As I said the goal is not to bother before loading of web resources and to bother specifically after loading resources. And our primary browser is Chrome.

Does any tools helps me to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the Net (or Network) tab of your browser's Developer tools. You have a detailed analysis of whether a resource is found and how much time it took to load.

Further, you can use tools such as [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) or [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) to gain further insight in how to improve the performance of your application. More in depth analysis is possible by using tools such as [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/), which analyse your application in terms of code and database queries.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely make use of Firebug for Firefox: http://getfirebug.com/. You'll be able to measure the duration of each resource being requested and delivered from the server (stylesheets, scripts, images).

If you're looking for something more "heavy-duty", be sure to check out New Relic's suite of products: http://newrelic.com

Quick tips:

- Minify scripts and stylesheets
- Compress images where possible
- Use server-side page caching
- Make use of gzip compression

Comment: These all helps to reduce load time. I am not bothering that. I am more specific about after loading how much time it tooks to to render the content. and in that process where are the bottle necks.

Comment: When you refer to "content", do you mean static HTML, images and the like? Are you asking: how long will it take to show text and images after my scripts and stylesheets load?

Comment: We are working on single page web application. We use multiple javascript libraries and frameworks which process the response data from the server(json) and process the data and update the DOM. I am not bothering about showing static content. I am more focusing on measuring the performance of this processing by javascript libraries and find out where the bottle necl

Comment: New Relic recently released support for measuring AJAX errors and performance, which you might find useful: http://blog.newrelic.com/2014/03/13/javascript-error-reporting-ajax-timing-new-relic/

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 navigation timing and use this bookmarklet http://66.7percentangel.com/2011/12/breaking-down-onload-event-performance-bookmarklet/ This will be more accurate than any other tool like YSlow or Page Speed because here the latencies are recorded by browser on the completion of appropriate event (page load, DOM ready etc.) On the other hand tools like YSlow use Date function in JS to get the current time. It is not accurate because Javascript runtime has a single threaded execution and it gives you the time when the request got served not when the request was made.